Why Functions are "datatype"?
We have 3 datatype groups in C (or any similar language):

Primitive
Derived
User Defined

and functions are in "Derived" group & it's called a "Datatype".
And why it's a datatype? It's a block of code that can do something and here people say: "well ok but there is a return value of function which can be a type of Primitive data types ...". This explanation doesn't make sense.
And why functions are there? Why is it recognized as a data type?

Function types exist, but they are not data types (not sure what makes you think they are). They are compound types (is that what you call "derived"?) because they contain other types in them (e.g. void(int) type (function taking int and returning void) is based on void and int).

[citation needed] for the definition and the "here people say" quote.

I did not see in the C standard any of those terms. Citation please

@HolyBlackCat: C 2024 6.2.5 says “Any number of derived types can be constructed from the object and function types, as follows:…” The italics indicating a defined term are in the original.

@0___________: Did you look? Every version of the C standard says there are “derived types.”

The C standard does not define “primitive” types or “user defined” types. It does not use the text “datatype” or “Datatype”. If you have seen those words used as you describe somewhere and want them explained, you should fully cite the source, including author, title, URL, and bibliographic details.

@EricPostpischil Ah, I was looking into the C++ standard...

The C standard does define basic types, which are char, the signed anbd unsigned integer types, and the floating-point types. Function types are called derived types because each one is constructed from other types, by specifying which types are the return type and the parameter types of the function.

Function types are types because functions are referred to with identifiers and other expressions in C source code, and the compiler needs to know how to interpret those identifiers and expressions. Types convey information about the meanings of expressions. For example, in foo(x) * y, the type of foo indicates the type of value it returns, which tells the compiler how that value will be returned (such as in which processor register) and possibly whether to perform integer multiplication or floating-point multiplication for the *.

big thanks to
– Eric Postpischil ,– HolyBlackCat , 0___________ ,  Guy Incognito

special thank to @EricPostpischil ,,, i think i have to read the standard itself and not third party websites ...
